# Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 Static IP breaks internet

Tags: 14.04, server

I'm trying to setup Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 with a static IP via /etc/network/interfaces

When the entry is

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I get an IP 10.10.10.228 from my DHCP server and I can ping 8.8.8.8 and google.ca

When I modify the entry to

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.10.10.116
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.10.10.0
broadcast 10.10.10.255
gateway 10.10.10.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

and refresh the network interface by doing a

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

I can still ping my gateway 10.10.10.1 and other devices like LAN printers, servers, PCs.  However, I cannot ping any public address like 4.2.2.2 or 8.8.8.8 nor can I ping google.ca.  The moment I switched back to dhcp, internet works again.

I checked route -n and ip route and both static and dhcp gives me the same readout.  I'm not really sure why it doesn't work.

Edit: here's the route -n output

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

and here's the ip route output

```
default via 10.10.10.1 dev eth0
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.10.116
```

Looks ok to me but not working.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the `.116` address is already in use by another device on the segment? what happens if you statically assign the original DHCP-supplied address `10.10.10.228`?

Comment: .116 is not in use for sure.  I tripled checked but yes I can try with .228 right now.

Comment: Seems like your router is configured to not accept that address or to not accept an address it did not assign.

Comment: No that's not it.  We have a dhcp server.  The router does nothing about assigning IPs.  I think something funky happened on the host but it worked after a restart.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between using DHCP and static addresses is that the 'gateway' box in question here knows to set up a NAT (Network Address Translation) table when using DHCP, because it knows the IP address it gave your host.  With a statically assigned address, the 'gateway' doesn't get its NAT tables updated.  So whilst the packet may be being successfully forwarded outside to the internet, the gateway doesn't know what to do with the return/reply packets because its NAT wasn't configured.

So we need to configure the gateway box to use NAT for the .116 address.  If the gateway is a standard access point, they usually allow for static IP configuration by MAC (Media Access Controller) address via its web configuration interface:  give it the .116 address and the (.116 host's) MAC address (displayed using the 'ifconfig' command with the title 'HWaddr'), and set the host back to DHCP, and that way your host will have a static IP address the gateway knows to NAT.

Comment: I'm not sure then why on Windows Servers you can assign Static IPs anytime, anywhere.  I also assume you want me to add a static ARP entry in my firewall?

Comment: And I just checked, my firewall already has a dynamic arp entry for .116 and it points to the same MAC as the computer hosting Ubuntu Server.  And that is as I expect as that's how network devices work.

Comment: sorry, I don't know what Windows servers do, but ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) is only for resolving host IP addresses from local MAC addresses; it doesn't do anything outside the innermost ethernet network: My only reason for mentioning MAC addresses is because that uniquely identifies the Ubuntu Server (.116) to the gateway box, such that the gateway box can be configured to assign the .116 IP address from the the server's MAC address via DHCP.  More info on the nature of the gateway box might help here, assuming this solution is acceptable...

Comment: Oh.. I see what you mean, so set something like static DHCP assignment from router to always provide .116 address to a specific MAC address.  Sorry I misread your answer.  For some reason after a real restart, it's working... I didn't touch any configuration at all lol.

Answer (score 0):

I actually shutdown the server via shutdown now command and restarted it, and now static ip works.  I thought using the reboot command was enough.  Not really sure what happened but it is working now.